# Qt 5.3 configuration error for VisualStudio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, configuration

I am relatively new to the Qt. At the moment I'm trying to configure Qt library for my machine before installing add-in for VisualStudio'10. I tried to download Qt library only (withouth a Qt creator IDE), and found "qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.2.zip" and extracted it to my external drive: "F:\Programs\Qt\5.3.2". Then I run command "configure" on VisualStudio command prompt.

```css
F:\Programs\VStudio'10\VC>cd F:\Programs\Qt\5.3.2

F:\Programs\Qt\5.3.2>configure
```

After a while it gave me following error:

```css
Running configuration tests...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'F:\Programs\VStudio'10\VC\BIN\link.EXE' : return cod
e '0x463'
Stop.
Could not find output file: No such file or directory
WARNING: The DirectX SDK could not be detected:
  There is no Direct X SDK installed or the environment variable "DXSDK_DIR" is
not set.
Disabling the ANGLE backend.

WARNING: Using OpenGL ES 2.0 without ANGLE.
Specify -opengl desktop to use Open GL.
The build will most likely fail.
```

On the installation instruction that was found on Qt webpage, it was said to set environmental variables: "Add this 2 paths to the Environment Variables: “C:\Qt\2009.01\bin” and
“C:\Qt\2009.01\qt\bin”." But I was unable to find any "bin" directory in my qt-everywhere folder. Instead I set up following variable to my path: "F:\Programs\Qt\5.3.2\Qtbase\bin". Still no help.

How can I resolve these issues? Any ideas and help are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've done is more like attempting to prepare building Qt itself from the source code (but that is not exactly how to do that, anyway). You don't need that at least now but when you start customize Qt framework, say, for static build. That is when configure tool comes handy. And you will need to [read](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/configure-options.html) on that.

You need just to download its installer from: http://qt-project.org/downloads

I assume you don't have prebuilt Qt and Qt Creator in your system but that is prerequisite for what you want to do. Take either Community version or [start download](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) immediately. After you've installed certain Qt version for your platform including Qt Creator (which is native Qt IDE) you will also be able to install and use Visual Studio AddIn. And then take Visual Studio AddIn for Qt 5 from: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.3-opensource.exe and install it. Read the [instruction](http://doc.qt.digia.com/vs-add-in/index.html) on how to use it. There will be some new menu for importing Qt project, though.

BTW, Qt Creator itself is not bad at all and maybe preferable for most of Qt development tasks except some debugging. I maintain entire project in Qt Creator and write the code there and only occasionally go to Visual Studio with AddIn installed to import Qt project there for some better debug experience.

Comment: What I'm trying is to configure Qt before installing add-in. I've watched many tutorials on youtube and some manuals that exactly suggest the same way I'm doing it.



Due to my hardware storage limitations, I've decided to install Qt add-in only, instead of Qt Creator IDE, since I have already VS'10. But if you suggest so, and there is no other solution I can try to install everything

Comment: And I am an active developer and build Qt as well (that is what configure for).

Comment: Your VS 2010 also needs to be higher than Express edition. I use VS 2012 and 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I'm neither trying to argue with you , nor I have a doubt in your knowledge in this area. As I mentioned I'm the newbie one, so can you please have a look at this [Qt installation Manual for VS](http://portfolio.delinkx.com/files/Qt.pdf) and help resolve my confusion please? I have VS'10 professional edition

Comment: I glanced at that pdf document. It is not explaining configure tool well enough. Maybe original explanation from qt-project.org is a bit more informative? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/configure-options.html *configure is a command-line tool which determines how to build Qt for a particular platform.* You only need to build Qt itself when you know why, BTW. It is quite a work for your PC and requires quite a lot of disk space. Otherwise, you can just use prebuilt Qt modules for certain OS/bitness/compiler as I suggested above.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I cant find the solution for this I'll follow you advice. Sorry that Im bot being able to upvote your answer because of my low reputation. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can try run "configure -opengl"

or , you can download Microsoft DirectX SDK and install it ,then try again.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812

Comment: Running "configure -opengl" still gives same result. On the manual of installation it was said that all needed SDK's for Qt are in VS'10, so I doubted, but I will install it. However, what do you think about that NMAKE error? What causes it?